# Adding role to user does not work, giving "Missing Permissions" error - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have started making a Discord bot which follows basic commands like kick, ban, etc. I was trying to make a verify function which adds the "Member" role to a user when they activate the command. However, when the bot tries running the line `await author.add_roles(role)`, it gives back this error:

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `verify`:
...
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I have checked if the bot has the right permissions to execute this command, and it does. It has the Administrator permission which should be enough to give a role to a user.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
@slash.slash(
    name="verify",
    description="...",
    guild_ids=guilds
)

async def _verify(ctx: SlashCommand):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Member")
    if role not in ctx.author.roles: # I am using ctx.author instead of ctx.message.author, because this is a slash command.
        await author.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 1):

I totally forgot that you cannot manage a role above yours, and I had the Member role above the bot's role. This is why it gave the error.